# Is it possible to receive push notifications in background mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk, push-notification

Is it possible to receive all push notifications that app recieved in background mode.
I mean that when app runned and then app went to background mode and then app recieve push notifications(in background mode) and user does not press view button on alert message (this button run app) and after some minutes user launch app, in this point I want get all push notifications that my app recieve in background mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, applications can and do receive Push Notifications whether they are backgrounded or not even active. In your `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method you can check to see if your app has received a notification, then handle it from there.

Comment: How check to see if my app has received a notificaiton in background mode?